# An Overclocking Software Compatible With 16h Family CPU/APUs

Tags: hpc

I have tried different overclocking software (BrazosTweaker, AMD Overdrive) and none are compatible with 16h family CPU/APUs. I want to overclock my 1.50GHz CPU to maybe 2.00GHz but I can't without a software for it.

Comment: Can't you increase the CPU frequency in the BIOS?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt If that only works with Intel, I use AMD and a normal ACER motherboard.